# Create a dictionary for the token, tags of a text

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a tagged text and I want to make a dictionary of the token and the tags of the text.
I tried this

```
text = "he/s is/v a/p good/j man/n"

dic = {}
for w in text.split():
    ti = w.split('/')
    tok =ti[0] 
    tag =ti[1]
    dic[tok] = tag
    print dic
```

this is the output

```
{'he': 's'}
{'is': 'v', 'he': 's'}
{'a': 'p', 'is': 'v', 'he': 's'}
{'a': 'p', 'is': 'v', 'good': 'j', 'he': 's'}
{'a': 'p', 'is': 'v', 'good': 'j', 'man': 'n', 'he': 's'}
```

How can I do to prevent duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not creating any duplicates. Just place the print statement outside for loop not inside as:

```
for w in text.split():
    ti = w.split('/')
    tok =ti[0] 
    tag =ti[1]
    dic[tok] = tag
print dic
```

Output will be:

```
{'a': 'p', 'is': 'v', 'good': 'j', 'man': 'n', 'he': 's'}
```

You can create this dictionary in an easy way like this:

```
>>> text = "he/s is/v a/p good/j man/n"
>>> dict([i.split('/') for i in text.split()])
{'a': 'p', 'is': 'v', 'good': 'j', 'man': 'n', 'he': 's'}
```

Comment: why is it not in the order of the text?

Comment: This is because python dictionaries are unordered data structures. Order is not required in dictionaries as any value can be directly accessed by its key.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your `print` inside the for loop you can do all with list comprehension . First split your string by space (`s.split()`) then by `/` :

```
>>> {i:j for i,j in [i.split('/') for i in s.split()]}
{'a': 'p', 'is': 'v', 'good': 'j', 'man': 'n', 'he': 's'}
```